# Run Macro after OLAP Query

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, olap

This is my Workbook:

#### Sheets layout:

1. `Source`: Pivot Table with Analysis Services connection
2. `Distributors`: Stuff to be sorted connected with the Pivot
3. `Output`: Chart based on sorted data of `Distributors` + Slicers connected to Pivot

What I need to do is: **Launch `Sorting` Macro after each OLAP Query (= each time I use the slicers).**

#### Sorting Code

```
Sub Sorting()

'This line finds the last occupied row in column A
'And you can use that LR variable in all the following Range Statements.
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Distributors").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Distributors").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C4:C102" & LR) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Distributors").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A3:C102" & LR)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Distributors").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Distributors").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D4:D102") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Distributors").Sort
        .SetRange Range("D3:F102")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. **Launch Macro after each Pivot Update**

1. Alt+F11, Right click on Source (Sheet with PivotTable)
2. View Code
3. Insert the Event trigger

*Event Trigger*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
'your_macro_here
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that you can't enter reference to a Module. Insert directly your macro.